# sms not showing in inbox

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am creating sms app and here is the code for sms receiver and the AndroidManifest.xml :-

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import com.arays.sms.MainActivity;
import com.arays.sms.R;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        String str2 = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                str2 += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                // str2 += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }

            Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(str2));
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,
                    new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME }, null,
                    null, null);
            try {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String displayName = c.getString(0);
                str2 = displayName;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                c.close();
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);

            String uri = "tel:" + str2;
            Intent iph = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
            PendingIntent pCall = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, iph, 0);

            // Build notification

            Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(str))
                    .setContentTitle("New sms from " + str2)
                    .setContentText(str)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_chat)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_call, "Call", pCall)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_accept, "Read", pIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_discard, "Delete", pIntent)
                    .build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // hide the notification after its selected
            noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            // notification
            notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
        }
    }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.arays.sms"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.arays.sms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.arays.sms.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.arays.sms.fragments.MessagesFragment"
            android:label="MessagesFragment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.arays.sms.fragments.ContactsFragment"
            android:label="ContactsFragment"
            android:parentActivityName="com.arays.sms.MainActivity" >
        </activity>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.arays.sms.services.SmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
        <activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service
            android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but the problem is when i set my app as default sms app it wont show the sms in inbox. I get the notification with sms text and number but the msg is not there in inbox of my app or any other sms app on my phone. what i am doing wrong here any help. do i need to update the sms database in the receiver.

thank you

Comment: Is you code that generates your inbox only looking at the SMS database?  Because I don't see you writing it to the SMS database anywhere here, and if you're the default receiver I think you need to do that.

Comment: so i need to update the sms database? how can i do that i am new in android would be really helpfull if you share some links

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
        contentvalues.put("address", str2);
        contentvalues.put("body", str);
        contentvalues.put("seen", Integer.valueOf(1));
        context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), contentvalues)
```